# Problem in receiving first Message by Smack

Tags: java, xmpp, smack

I use below code to send messages.

```
 // Assume we've created an XMPPConnection name "connection".
ChatManager chatmanager = connection.getChatManager();
Chat newChat = chatmanager.createChat("jsmith@jivesoftware.com", new MessageListener() {
    public void processMessage(Chat chat, Message message) {
        System.out.println("Received message: " + message);
    }
});

try {
    newChat.sendMessage("Howdy!");
}
catch (XMPPException e) {
    System.out.println("Error Delivering block");
}
```

And below  for receiving messages sent to my JabberID, asynchronously.

```
// Create a packet filter to listen for new messages from a particular
// user. We use an AndFilter to combine two other filters.
PacketFilter filter = new AndFilter(new PacketTypeFilter(Message.class), 
        new FromContainsFilter("mary@jivesoftware.com"));
// Assume we've created an XMPPConnection name "connection".

// First, register a packet collector using the filter we created.
PacketCollector myCollector = connection.createPacketCollector(filter);
// Normally, you'd do something with the collector, like wait for new packets.

// Next, create a packet listener. We use an anonymous inner class for brevity.
PacketListener myListener = new PacketListener() {
        public void processPacket(Packet packet) {
            // Do something with the incoming packet here.
        }
    };
// Register the listener.
connection.addPacketListener(myListener, filter);
```

Sending message is ok.

But receiving message from another JabberID don't achived until I send a message to that JabberID.

And after that I receive messages sent by it properly.

Note that I often need to receive messages from jabberIDs that are not in my list and often My application is not the side that begins a chat.

Upper codes are smack samples but my code is completely same except I don't create PacketListener implementation inline.

Comment: While I'm thinking on your problem, please have a close look at [debugging with smack](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/documentation/debugging.html). I was able to solve almost every problem after simlpy switched on the debugger ;-)

Comment: Is your code complete? I don't any invocation to myCollector.nextPacket()...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My problem solved when I stopped using Jabber Client with the same user logined during I test my program. 
In other words code is correct but Jabber client catches sent messages and remain no things for my program to catch.

Answer (score 0):

It's been quite a while since I worked with smack, but I managed to start chats based on incoming messages.

If I remember well, I had some sort of "ChatRegistry", a simple `Map<String, Chat>` where the key was equal to the chat partners id. Then I listened to incoming messages, extracted the jabber id and looked up the active chat session with this partner. If there wasn't an active session, I created a new Chat and added the new key/vale pair to the registry.

Comment: I couldn't find ChatRegistry or sometings like it and I think there is a wrong loop in your suggestion: if I know who wants to send me a message then no problem exists.

Answer (score 0):

Just a bit confused. You say

> Upper codes are smack samples but my code is completely same except I don't create PacketListener implementation inline.

How do you receive messages without having a PacketListener implementation? I would think that you would always receive messages from chats you started because of the code below

> Chat newChat = chatmanager.createChat("jsmith@jivesoftware.com", new MessageListener() {
>       public void processMessage(Chat chat, Message message) {
>           System.out.println("Received message: " + message);
>       }
>   });

But in order to asynchronously wait for incoming messages, I would think you will need a PacketListener. 
I might have totally misunderstood the problem you are facing though

(This should have been a comment, but I can't figure how to add one)

Comment: 1. I implement PacketListener but not inline

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while, did you manage to solve this? why are you creating FromContainsFilter? In that way, your listeners processes only packets from the given user, not all packets.